# How to change ActionBar background color in API level 21

Tags: android

I add following code, but it is for API level 14

```
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: Are you using AppCopmat library? If not, Material theme does not have a default action bar so`android:actionBarStyle` is ignored. You have to have a `Toolbar` in your layout and call `setActionBar(Toolbar)` with it. Since the toolbar is a part of your layout you specify its background directly in XML.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have used to do the job, but I was using AppCompat.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
</style>


<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
     <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_foreground</item>
</style>
```

And make a drawable called **actionbar_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>

</shape>
```

Don't forget to update AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">
```

[image]

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        
    </style>

    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="color">#fb8c00</item>
    </style>
Thanx bojan. I do like this. But it is not working.

Comment: Did you apply the new theme in your manifest? I works on my lolipop one plus. See the image above, it's from v5.1.1 android

Comment: Did you mean android:targetSdkVersion="21" in manifest. Already i added this code

Comment: No, the theme name. `android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"`

Comment: I added android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" to manifest

Answer (score 0):

```
<resources>
  <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Taken from [Android developer](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) site.

You need to basically use the `colorPrimary` value to denote Action Bar color. There are others as well to show status bar color and all, which you can find in the link.

Answer (score 0):

`ToolBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);`

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in API 21:

if you use `AppCompatActivity`

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.<YOUR_COLOR>)));
```